# Generating sparse vectors in a subspace (of $\mathbb{R}^n$)

Tags: vector-spaces, sparsity

I have an orthonormal basis for a given subspace (of $\mathbb{R}^n$). I am also given the sparsest ($l_0$ norm) vector direction (since $l_0$ norm is independent of scaling) belonging to the subspace (obtained using [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiZkZzt8cnVAhXF6Y8KHcVvD9QQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fabs%2F1412.4659&usg=AFQjCNGHhp2B7CeKzSl8wP89_xBGdSvyqA) algorithm). Using this information, is there any efficient way to generate the $2^{nd}$ sparsest vector (direction) in the subspace?

Comment: You probably want an _independent_ second vector.

Comment: What properties should a second sparsest vector have?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Not sure what you mean by independent in this context. If you mean linearly independent of the sparsest vector, then yes. That goes without saying as the $l_0$ norm is constant on scaling vectors.

Comment: @mathreadler The second sparsest vector should be linearly independent of the sparsest vector (and not equal to zero, of course). No other specific properties are to be satisfied. It must only be a member of the subspace.

Comment: Then maybe you have enough information to start formulating an approch.

Comment: @mathreadler The second sparsest vector would be a local mimimum of the linear program used to solve for the sparseness condition. I am not really sure how to converge the solution to the $2^{nd}$ sparsest with high probability (i.e. without creating a large enough set of linear programs and brute forcing over the generated set of (hopefully distinct) local minima).

Answer (score 1):

Here is **one approach**

---

Span the **complement** to the subspace, build a matrix from it with basis vectors as rows, call it $\bf M$.

Now for a column vector $\bf v$ to lie in the subspace : $\bf Mv = 0$ must hold, alright? This gives us a first optimization term $\|\bf Mv\|_2^2$. This is also true if we have a collection of vectors stored in a matrix, say $\bf V = [v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n]$ with the corresponding optimization term $$\|\bf MV\|_F^2$$ Okay? Now we want $\bf v_1$ to be sparser than $\bf v_2$ which is sparser than $\bf v_3$ etc. It is well known we can get close to $L_1$ solutions using *iterated reweighting* of linear programs, where weights ${\bf W}_{ii}$ on the entries of the vectors $\bf \|Wv\|_2^2$ increase the closer ${\bf v}_i$ was to 0 ( in the previous iteration ). Now we will need to vectorize our $\bf V$, since otherwise it would be difficult to choose individual $\bf W$ matrices for each ${\bf v}_k$, something that is required to achieve an order of importance of sparsity.

---

Now what is left is something to avoid getting $\bf 0$-vector solutions, and to find good sequence of functions $f_l$ for the reweighting: $$({{\bf W_{k+1}})_l} = f_l({{(\bf W_k})_l},({\bf v_k})_l), \text{ where } \cases{k \text{ is iteration number }\\ l \text{ is vector number}}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think iterated reqeighting might be a good way to go. As in Candés' paper, I think reweighting by $\frac{1}{|v_k|}$ should work based on the analytical results presented. To avoid zero vector solutions, the $\| v \|_2 = 1$ constraint can be added to the LP (since we are good comparing solutions that lie on the unit ball).

Comment: Yes, just be careful to not divide by 0 if $|v_k|=0$. $\|v\|_2=1$ is not a very linear constraint, I think. So you will need to find a linearization for it.

Comment: Yes, duly noted. Candés' reweighs by $\frac{1}{|v_k|+\epsilon}$,for some appropriately defined $\epsilon$, I think. On the topic of sparse representation, are you aware of any references dealing with the sparseness properties of random subspaces (probability of random subspaces having $1, 2 \dots$ sparse vectors).

Comment: Yes that reweighting and similar ones I have also tried with some success. I have not studied much about spaces spanned by sparse vectors, but I often work with sparse matrices as operators.